# Converting date/time and generating offsets in bash script

Tags: bash, datetime, date, time

I need a script to do some date/time conversion. It should take as an input a particular time. It should then generates a series of offsets, in both hour:minute form and number of milliseconds elapsed.

For 03:00, for example, it should give back 04:02:07 (3727000ms*) 05:04:14 (7454000ms), 06:06:21 etc...

How would I go about doing this as a bash script? Ideally it would work on both Mac OS X and Linux (Ubuntu or Debian).

- (1hr * 60 minutes/hr *60 seconds/minute *1000ms/sec )+(2min*60 sec/min * 1000ms/sec)+(7sec*1000ms/sec) = (60*60*1000)+(2*60*1000)+(7*1000) = 3727000

Comment: What have you tried?® By the way, part of the answer is in your bullet point.

Comment: It certainly seems like you're just wanting us to write your programs for you.  I would be happy to if you're willing to pay me.  Otherwise, I'd advise looking at the [date](http://ss64.com/bash/date.html) command and coming back when you have a specific question.

Comment: I've tried the date command, but that only lets me work with the _current_ time. (Unless I want to change the system time, which I don't). I want to use some arbitrary time as the starting point, and the date command doesn't support that.

Comment: `date -d` lets you give arbitrary dates.  You can even use `+ 1 second/day/whatever` with the `-d` flag.  For example, `date -d '20120501 + 1 day'` returns `Wed May  2 00:00:00 CDT 2012`.

Comment: Dennis: Yeah, I guessed as much, which is why I included it. But I'm not sure how to convert an input of "03:00" into a usable format that I can than feed the relevant equation. I'm also not sure how to handle the rollovers (e.g from 01:59:00 to 02:00:00 when I add 1 minute).

Comment: Tim: Ah, I see where the confusion is -- my version of date doesn't have that! (OS X 10.5)

Comment: @3dan Holy piss, you're not lying.  I thought surely you were mistaken and there was *some* way to display arbitrary dates with the osx date command, but [there's not](http://ss64.com/osx/date.html).  In that case I would recommend either using another language with date utilities or installing [macports](http://www.macports.org/).  Working with dates manually is pretty notoriously hard.  (Actually macports is pretty indispensable for me.  Totally worth your time.).

Answer (score 2):

```
time2ms () {
    local time=$1 hour minute second
    hour=${time%%:*}
    minute=${time#$hour:}
    minute=${minute%:*}
    second=${time#$hour:$minute}
    second=${second/:}
    echo "$(( ( (10#${hour} * 60 * 60) + (10#${minute} * 60) + 10#${second} ) * 1000 ))"
}

ms2time () {
    local ms=$1 hour minute second
    ((second = ms / 1000 % 60))
    ((minute = ms / 1000 / 60 % 60))
    ((hour = ms / 1000 / 60 / 60))
    printf '%02d:%02d:%02d\n' "$hour" "${minute}" "${second}"
}

show_offsets () {
    local time=$1 interval=$2 time_ms interval_ms new_time
    time_ms=$(time2ms "$time")
    interval_ms=$(time2ms "$interval")
    new_time=$(ms2time $((time_ms + interval_ms)) )
    echo "$new_time (${interval_ms}ms)"
}
```

Demos:

```
$ show_offsets 03:00 1:02:07
04:02:07 (3727000ms)
$ show_offsets 03:00 2:04:14
05:04:14 (7454000ms)
$ show_offsets 03:00 3:06:21
06:06:21 (11181000ms)
```